Difference between an orthonormal frame and normal coordinates
I want to verify that my understanding of this topic is correct. Consider a manifold M, with metric tensor $\mathbf{g}$ and coordinates some spacetime coordinates $x^\mu$. The metric tensor in coordinate basis is given by
\begin{equation}
\mathbf{g}=g_{\mu\nu}\tilde{dx}^\mu \otimes \tilde{dx}^\nu
\end{equation}
where I'm using bold face to denote any $(n,m)$ tensor and $\tilde{dx}^\mu$ and the following notation for my basis and dual basis
\begin{equation}
\begin{aligned}
\vec{\partial}_\mu&:\text{Coordinate basis vectors}\\
\tilde{dx}^\mu&:\text{Coordinate dual-basis 1-forms}\\
\vec{e}_{\hat{\mu}}&: \text{Orthonormal basis vectors}\\
\tilde{e}^{\hat{\mu}}&:\text{Orthonormal dual-basis 1-forms}
\end{aligned}
\end{equation}
With this notation, something like the components of the coordinate basis vectors on an orthonormal frame would be $\big(\vec{\partial}_\mu\big)^{\hat{\alpha}}$.
Orthonormal frame
This basis is defined by
\begin{equation}
\vec{e}_{\hat{\mu}}\cdot \vec{e}_{\hat{\nu}}=\eta_{\hat{\mu}\hat{\nu}}
\end{equation}
Here $\eta$ is the Minkowski metric. This condition means the basis vectors are orthonormal, with the time component having norm $-1$ since we are in a pseudo-Riemannian manifold.
An equivalent statement is that the metric tensor in an orthonormal frame has components that look like a flat metric
\begin{equation}
\mathbf{g}=\eta_{\hat{\mu}\hat{\nu}}\tilde{e}^{\hat{\mu}}\otimes \tilde{e}^{\hat{\nu}}
\end{equation}
There are two facts I want to corroborate:

This does NOT mean that the dynamics of this metric tensor are flat in any meaningful physical way; we just "hid" the curvature in the frame. In other words, if you are in a curved spacetime and use orthonormal frames, your Ricci scalar will still give you the curvature of spacetime and geodesics will look accelerated for generic observers.
There is no approximation here. The frame is a field that can be evaluated at any point in the manifold.

Normal (a.k.a. Riemann) coordinates
Normal coordinates are obtained by a change of coordinates, as opposed to a change of frame. We go to new coordinates $y$ such that, in the new coordinate system, the metric looks flat around some fixed point $y_0$
\begin{equation}
g_{\mu\nu}(y_0+\Delta y)=\eta_{\mu\nu}+O(\Delta y^2)
\end{equation}
Then, as long as we stay at $y_0$ and do local experiments that don't describe things moving far in $\Delta y$, physics DO look flat and the metric is truly Minkowski. Normal coordinates are exactly the opposite of what I described for orthonormal frames:

They describe the local physics of a free-falling observer as special relativity. So up to corrections in the distance squared, there is no gravity. Hence, the Ricci scalar at point $y_0$ would be flat up to quadratic corrections in distance, and objects move on straight lines up to corrections quadratic in distance.
By that same statement, they are an approximation valid only locally around point $y_0$.

Confusion about Christoffel symbols
The Chrsitoffel symbols
\begin{equation}
\Gamma^\alpha_{\mu\nu}(x)=\frac{1}{2}g^{\alpha\beta}\big(g_{\beta\mu,\nu}+g_{\mu\beta,\nu}-g_{\mu\nu,\beta}\big)
\end{equation}
in Normal coordinates are
\begin{equation}
\Gamma^\alpha_{\mu\nu}(y_0+\Delta y)=0+O(\Delta y^2)
\end{equation}
Now, when it comes to the Christoffel symbols in an orthonormal frame... we are not allowed to calculate them directly on the orthonormal basis, right? Something like this:
\begin{equation}
\Gamma^{\hat{\alpha}}_{\hat{\mu}\hat{\nu}}(x)=^?\frac{1}{2}g^{\hat{\alpha}\hat{\beta}}\big(g_{\hat{\beta}\hat{\mu},\hat{\nu}}+g_{\hat{\mu}\hat{\beta},\hat{\nu}}-g_{\hat{\mu}\hat{\nu},\hat{\beta}}\big)
\end{equation}
because this would just be zero for all points on spacetime! Are we not allowed to do this because the Christoffel symbols are not a tensor? Instead, we could calculate them by using the change of basis matrices $\big(\vec{\partial}_\alpha\big)^{\hat{\alpha}}$ (i.e., the coordinate basis vectors written in an orthonormal frame)
\begin{equation}
\begin{aligned}
\Gamma^{\hat{\alpha}}_{\hat{\mu}\hat{\nu}}&=\Gamma^{\alpha}_{\mu\nu}\big(\vec{\partial}_\alpha)^{\hat{\alpha}}\big(\tilde{dx}^\mu\big)_{\hat{\mu}}\big(\tilde{dx}^\nu\big)_{\hat{\nu}}\\
&\neq0
\end{aligned}
\end{equation}
This would only be zero if we pick coordinates such that the first term on the rhs vanishes, but then we are using normal coordinates.

For the first approach, the keyword is tetrad formalism. In short, the Christoffel symbols are not symmetric anymore (the connection is not torsion free), so you just have the torsion contribution your formula needs to be generalized. Tong gives a nice short introduction in his lecture notes

An orthonormal frame is exactly orthonormal everywhere, but might not be realized as the frame of any coordinate system. Normal coordinates give a frame that looks orthonormal to first order near a point. You can't conclude that anything is approximately flat ("no gravity up to corrections") from normal coordinates, as the second derivatives of the metric don't go away. Actually such coordinates exist even at points with extreme gravity - and anyway curvatures are frame/coordinate independent.
Your confusion about the connection is justified: most books only cover orthonormal frames (tetrad formalism) and coordinate frames separately, but they can also be treated together.
For a general frame $e_\mu$ (which is a collection of $d$ vector fields linearly independent at each point) there are two important  quantities: the metric coefficients $e_\mu \cdot e_\nu = g_{\mu \nu}$ and the Lie bracket coefficients $[e_\mu,e_\nu] = L_{\mu \nu \lambda} \, e^{\lambda}$.
If the Lie coefficients $L_{\mu \nu \lambda}=0$ all vanish then the basis is "holonomic" which is equivalent to being "a coordinate basis for some coordinate system". If $g_{\mu \nu} = \eta_{\mu \nu}$ the basis is orthonormal.
Defining connection coefficients by $\nabla_{e_\mu} e_{\nu} = \Gamma_{\mu \nu \lambda} \, e^{\lambda}$, the general formula for Levi-Civita connection is
$$ \Gamma_{\mu \nu \lambda} = 
\tfrac{1}{2} ( \partial_{e_\mu} g_{\nu \lambda} - \partial_{e_\lambda} g_{\mu \nu} + \partial_{e_\nu} g_{\lambda \mu})
+
\tfrac{1}{2} ( L_{\mu \nu \lambda} -  L_{\nu \lambda \mu} +  L_{\lambda \mu \nu}). $$
Note that the partial derivatives are not coordinate derivatives but are the action of a vector on a scalar field. For a holonomic (coordinate) basis this recovers the standard formula. For an orthonormal basis it recovers the spin connection for tetrads.
You can quickly see that the existence of a holonomic orthonormal frame is equivalent to flatness (connection coefficients globally zero implies zero Riemann tensor). Normal coordinates give a holonomic basis that is orthonormal at a point but not everywhere.
Hope this helps clarify something! For derivations eg Sec. 6  of these notes, or you can scour the depths of MTW where I believe the general form of connection also appears somewhere.

This is a wonderful answer! Thanks!

Hi, thanks for this useful answer. I followed the link to your notes for more detail, but saw that you stressed that your notes use reciprocal vectors rather than dual vectors. Given that reciprocal vectors weren't mentioned in this answer, I'm wondering whether it is an important distinction for sections 1-6? thanks

@JoeSchindler also I feel that your answer could more clearly distinguish between a frame field and a frame (an ordered set of basis vectors at a point)?

Hi, thanks, good questions. About dual vectors - it's really just a formal distinction. You can pass back and forth between vectors and dual vectors with the canonical isomorphism "v  ~ inner product with v". So you can use dual vectors, it's just that you don't need to. I should have phrased that differently in the notes. Technically speaking the "reciprocal" version is nicer - for instance here we are using "all indices down" Christoffel/Lie symbols, without jumping through any hoops. But you can cook up the same with dual vectors as well if desired

I usually use "frame" and "frame field" synonymously, and use "basis" when referring to the tangent space at a single point. But you're right that "frame field" is really the more descriptive term, I hope it didn't cause too much confusion
